# Finding count of fields in DB with special condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

my question is:
If i have table student with student_id and other fields(not matter)
and table exam with three fields: student_id, subject_id(id from another table subject) and exam_mark.

I need to find count of students who have the same exam marks for each subject.

I have stuck on that task, you can get me idea how can i do or explain full solution.

Simple data:

[image]

For this scenario query must return count(student_id) = 4

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need nested aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from
 (
   select student_id
   from tab
   group by student_id
   -- same min and max means only one value exists
   having min(exam_mark) = max(exam_mark)
 ) as dt
```

The min/max is usually more efficient than `COUNT(DISTINCT exam_mark) = 1`.

If you want only students with multiple marks enhance HAVING with

```
    AND count(*) > 1
```